# Insert data in pivot table Controller Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, controller, pivot-table, laravel-8

I have two tables with many to many relationship:

- `courriers`
- `structures`
- `courrier_structure`

The pivot table contains:

- `id`
- `courrier_id`
- `structure_id`
- `valide`

`valide` is a boolean attribute.

In first case, I inserted the `courrier_id` and the `structure_id` via a form. Next, I wish to put 1 into the `valide` value when the user click on a button, and I wanna do this via the controller.

My models look like this:

```
class Courrier extends Model {
    public function structures()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Structure::class)->withTimestamps()
            ->withPivot('valide');
    }
}
```

```
class Structure extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'nom_structure',
    ];
    
    public function courriers(){

        return $this->belongsToMany(Courrier::class)->withTimestamps()
            ->withPivot('valide');
    }
}
```

My web route

```
Route::get('{id}/valider', [App\Http\Controllers\CourrierController::class, 'valider'])
    ->name('valider');
```

My view on blade:

```
@foreach($courriers as $key => $courrier)
<td>
    <a class='' onclick='return confirm("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir valider la réception de ce courrier?")' href="{{ route('valider',$courrier->id) }}"> 
        Valider 
    </a>
</td>
@endforeach
```

My controller where I get this error:

> Undefined property:
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::$id

```
public function valider( Request $rquest, Courrier $courrier) {
    $courrier->structures()->updateExistingPivot($courrier->structures()->id,
        [$request->valide = 1]
    );
    return redirect()->route('nvCourriersDMO');
}
```

And I'm working on fields where structure_id=1,

```
public function nvCourriersDMO(Request $request, Courrier $courrier)
    {
                     
        $courriers = Courrier::join('courrier_structure', 'courriers.id',         
    '=', 'courrier_structure.courrier_id')- 
   >where('courrier_structure.structure_id','=','1')- 
   >where('courrier_structure.valide','=',NULL)->get();
         
                
        return view("nvCourriersDMO", compact('courriers'));
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the error message to your question?

Comment: @shaedrich Yea it's done

Comment: To get properties from relationship, don't use parentheses: `$courrier->structure->id`. And isn't it plural (`structures`)?

Comment: @shaedrich it's in plural yeah it's just a mistake
Now I'm getting this error: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Because it is `belongsToMany`. Do you only need one item of the collection?

Comment: Yes, i need juste one

Comment: If you know, which one, use `$courrier->structures->find($id)->id` (if you already know the id, you can pass it right away. If not, search for another attribute), otherwise do something like that: `$courrier->structure->first()->id`

Comment: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: Looks like your collection is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel relationship methods are a little tricky sometimes. If you call the method using parentheses (as you are here), it returns a "relationship class" instance. In this case an instance of the `BelongsToMany` class.

If you call the method as a property (without parentheses), Laravel returns the relationship *target*. In this case a collection of `Structure` model instances.

This should do the trick:

```php
public function valider(Request $request, Courrier $courrier)
{
    $pivotIds = $courrier->structures()->allRelatedIds();

    $courrier->structures()->updateExistingPivot(
        $pivotIds,
        ['valide' => 1]
    );

    return redirect()->route('nvCourriersDMO');
}
```

Comment: Nothing is changing, it doesn't do anything, did you see my blade view and the web route?

Comment: The  $pivotIds = $courrier->structures()->allRelatedIds(); gives all the fields, in my case I wish to validate juste one if you're seeing what am talking about

Comment: `$pivotIds` should contain all of the pivot IDs between your given `Courrier` and its related `structures`. The `updateExistingPivot` method updates each of those pivot records. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Just one pivotId cause i've done this in my controller :
$courriers = Courrier::join('courrier_structure', 'courriers.id', '=', 'courrier_structure.courrier_id')->where('courrier_structure.structure_id','=','1')->where('courrier_structure.valide','=',NULL)->get();

Comment: You didn't mention that in the question. I think you need to clarify what you're currently doing, and what you're trying to achieve.